# Listview and Buttons inside scrollview android

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-scrollview

I am showing the user all of its data inside a listview.
Now I am adding 4 buttons below it for the user to Edit/ Delete/ Add To Favorite, Cancel.
The Listview will not scroll but it will display all content (Wrap_Content) the background Scrollview will scroll to show all 4 buttons at the bottom!
How do I make my view look like this?

[Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJVJi.png)

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/l1" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Fav"rounded_carddata"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/move"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Use ConstraintLayout. Which is the best layout to do all kind of layouts

Comment: Hey @Priyankagb, can you please give me an example for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#7C7777"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout">
</ListView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and It will look like this:
[image]